# Y axis doesn't show label name in R

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

I just started with R , I use RStudio.

Right now I am playing around with plots just  to see how they work.

Here is my data:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wp4gs8qamdo1irk/State_Zhvi_Summary_AllHomes.csv?dl=0

I have been trying to draw a barplot for $Zhvi against $RegionName

Here is my code :

```
labels <- allHomet$RegionName
mp<-barplot(round((allHomet$Zhvi)/1000,digits=2)[order(labels)],horiz=TRUE,las=1,col=c(palette(heat.colors(6,alpha=1))),
        border=NA,
        main="Price of housing in United states",
        xlab="Price",
        las=2 )!
```

[here is the plot I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnf15.png)

I don't get region name on the y axis,it shows blank .

Can any one tell me how I can make the region name appear?

Comment: Have a look at the 'names.arg' in '?barplot'

Comment: yes it populated the names by niw its messed up,here is the plothttps://www.dropbox.com/s/g7fxxbzy50bhhsh/Rplot01.png?dl=0

Comment: Try exporting the plot using the 'png' (or 'jpeg', 'pdf', etc.) function and fiddle with the dimensions (arguments 'hight' and 'width'). Setting a lower 'cex' may also help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that ggplot2 is ideally suited to dealing with. Its flexibility and modularity make it easy to knock-up graphs like this in no time:

```
library(ggplot2) # load graphics package
head(df)
fl <- as.character(rep(1:6, length.out = nrow(df))) # fill variable - anything here
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = RegionName, y = Zhvi, fill = fl), stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", name = "") +  # customise colours and legend title
  coord_flip() # make bars horizontal
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this it gives me this error :

Error : Mapping a variable to y and also using stat="bin".
  With stat="bin", it will attempt to set the y value to the count of cases in each group.
  This can result in unexpected behavior and will not be allowed in a future version of ggplot2.
  If you want y to represent counts of cases, use stat="bin" and don't map a variable to y.
  If you want y to represent values in the data, use stat="identity".
  See ?geom_bar for examples. (Defunct; last used in version 0.9.2)

Comment: Aha - ggplot2 has recently jumped to version 1.0, causing the above code to fail: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/release.html . Simple solution: add `stat = "identity",` just after `fill = fl), `. I've updated the answer to include this.